# FB.Apprequest popup not showing in unity5

Tags: unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk, facebook-app-requests

I am using facebook sdk package 7.5 for unity 5. Whenever I am sending app invite request without selecting friends it is working fine and popup is shown but whenever I am selecting friends and then trying to send request using FB.Apprequest popup is not shown.

Success response in coming in both cases.

Any help!!!